# Build Dependencies In Eclipse Java Library Project For Multiple Providers

Tags: java, eclipse, build, dependencies

We are writing a JMS library in Eclipse to be used in our applications. Preferably, we want this to work with many JMS providers.

So we build our code around java interfaces and create provider specific implementation classes as needed.

What happens with build dependencies in projects like this, when many people work on one library, each one on implementation classes for some specific provider?

Say I have WebSphere MQ and write the code for that provider. And another guy writes for ActiveMQ. And another for some other JMS provider. Are we all supposed to have the relevant jars on our build paths, or are we supposed to accept having build errors for the code written for the other providers.

Some thoughts we have are:
- to include the providers' jars with the project,
- have separate build ant tasks, one for each IDE/programmer,
- have the provider specific code in separate projects/jars???

None of the above looks perfect to us.
Any recommendations?

Thank you
tpav

Answer (score 0):

You provide an interface (or in this case you use the JMS interface) that is defined independantly from the providers - you have to have this interface in your workspace to make your project compilable. And during runtime you will need a provider present and configured in order to bind the interfaces to the current implementations.

To achieve this, you have to have the JMS interface available in the workspace. For the specific providers I suggest using separate projects (one for each provider), that can be added as needed for execution.

I also suggest taking a look at OSGi (specifically services and/or fragments), as it supports several items required in this case, however, it comes at a bit steep (but manageable) learning curve.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, in your 2nd paragraph, you suggest having the provider specific code in separate projects/jars. Which means having a main jar for the bulk of the code and smaller jars, one for each provider, isn't it?

Comment: So you don't think its overkill to have a separate jar for each JMS provider, just for the 4-5 provider specific classes/implementations of the relevant interfaces?

Comment: I understand your concern, but I think, the number of projects is less important, as if you name it accordingly, every user might know what is it for without looking into it. On the other hand, this approach would help during deployment: you select what you need to deploy, and that is easy to determine. So I think, although the number of jars/projects increase, your project becomes more maintainable from it.